# Creating spark data frame in RStudio

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

I have installed RStudio with R version 3.3.1 and apache Spark version 2.0.0 and I have successfully connected Rstudio with Spark. While I am creating a spark data frame using "df <- as.DataFrame(faithful)" it shows following error and I have tried with another example "df <- read.json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json")" also shows same error  Error][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0l8y.png)

My code

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:/Apache/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),"R","lib"), .libPaths()))
library(SparkR)
sparkR.session(appName = "MyApp")
**df <- as.DataFrame(faithful)** // Shows Error
```

[image]

Kindly help me out to solve this issue

Comment: What is the error? (Also please don't use pictures)

Comment: Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Sorry for that picture . I thought it will show all information. but it is not visible. The above is the actual error @Sotos

Comment: If `sc` is your sparkR.session, then try `createDataFrame(sc, faithful)`

Comment: Tried that too. got the same error @Sotos